# Unable to format timestamp as YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss in java

Tags: java, timestamp, simpledateformat

I have a timestamp 13 Dec 2018 19:37:18 which I need to convert to 2018-12-13 19:37:18, I am following the below steps but it is giving incorrect timestamp

```
     DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
     DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss");
     Date date = inputFormat.parse(updatedStartime);
     String NewStartTime = outputFormat.format(date);
```

I am getting the output as 2018-Jan-01 19:37:18, Do I need to convert the MMM to integer month value before formatting the output? what is the correct step to get the expected output?

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: `LocalDateTime.parse("13 Dec 2018 19:37:18", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMM u H:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))` yields `2018-12-13 19:37:18` (please break up into manageable pieces as in your question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`D` is "day in year"; not "day in month" what you actually need, so `d`.

`Y` is "week years"; i guess you meant `y` for normal year

So in all that would be:

```
    DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
```

For more details look at the javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Great, thanks ... it's working as expected..